# Why won't git-daemon serve my repository?

Tags: git, git-daemon

I set up `.git` in a directory on my local machine. I then run:

```
mkdir a
cd a
git init
git daemon
```

When I attempt to clone the repository in `a`, I get the following error:

```
mkdir b
cd b
git clone git://127.0.0.1
Initialized empty Git repository in /b/127.0.0.1/.git/
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How can I clone my repository over the git protocol?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to let `git-daemon` know it may export your repository:

```
$ git init --bare /tmp/my-repo.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/my-repo.git/

$ git daemon --verbose --base-path=/tmp --export-all /tmp/my-repo.git &

$ git clone git://`hostname`/my-repo.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/my-repo/.git/
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

A far better way is to run it from `xinetd`. Create and tweak `/etc/xinetd.d/git` along the lines of

```
# description: The git server offers access to git repositories
service git
{
        disable = no
        type            = UNLISTED
        port            = 9418
        socket_type     = stream
        wait            = no
        user            = nobody
        server          = /usr/local/bin/git
        server_args     = daemon --inetd --export-all --base-path=/pub/scm
        log_on_failure  += USERID
}
```

Don't forget to `sudo killall -HUP xinetd`. Now, all git repositories beneath `/pub/scm` will be available to anyone who asks.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Just to add that I found that if you want to be able to `git push` to the remote without using SSH you need to start the git daemon with the flag `--enable=receive-pack`. This allows [anonymous push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-daemon#Documentation/git-daemon.txt-receive-pack).

Answer (score 14):

You either have to put an empty file called `git-daemon-export-ok` into the repository or start `git daemon` with the `--export-all` option.

Quote from the git-daemon [man page](http://www.ru.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html):

> It verifies that the directory has the
>   magic file "git-daemon-export-ok", and
>   it will refuse to export any git
>   directory that hasn't explicitly been
>   marked for export this way (unless the
>   --export-all parameter is specified). If you pass some directory paths as
>   git daemon arguments, you can further
>   restrict the offers to a whitelist
>   comprising of those.

Comment: Just adding this:  In my case "git-daemon-export-ok" wasn't readable by the git-ro user that was running the daemon.